# Check if all the array members have the same value

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there an STL algorithm or fast technique to test if all the members of an array are set to the same value?

For example, I have an array with default values:

```
bool *finishFlags  =new (std::nothrow) bool[numOfBools];

    //Init all to false:

for(int i = 0 ; i < numOfBools; ++i){
   *finishFlags++ = false;
}
```

Now, during the runtime some of the array members are set to true and I want to test if all of them are set to the same value( true  in this case).Is there a fast way of doing it without typical array iteration?

Comment: Standard library algorithms are not magic, they would still need to iterate over the array.

Comment: If they're sorted, you can check the first and last.

Comment: If there is a chance that *some* of your values may end up `true`, set a variable to `true` whenever any member is set to true. Then you know "all false" is true or flase. If all flags can only be changed once (from false to true), increment a counter. When `counter=length(finishFlags)` all have been changed. For anything else ... you have to check the array. But oyu can stop checking at any point where you have found at least one `false` *and* one `true`.

Comment: If you are looking for STL algorithm, then this question shouldn't be tagged with **C**. By the way, STL should be replaced by standard C++ library.

Comment: @YuHao you are porbably right, but I was looking for any solution.Not just STL ;)

Comment: @MichaelIV: if the number of elements is fixed, you might want to use a bitset. Otherwise, you might want to reuse the same packing principle... however at one point you want to privilege setting up a value or checking for emptiness/fullness. If you set values many times but only check for equality once or twice, it might not be worth keeping a count of `true` elements.

Comment: Sidenote: your `finishFlags` variable will point to the end of the array after the loop you show, so hopefully you've saved a pointer to the original.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep a counter and add/subtract as the flags flip true or false.  Then `if ctr == numOfBools` or `ctr == 0` they are all the same.

Edit: Should have added that you need checks so you don't subtract if the bool is already off or add if it is already on.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you've stored and updated metadata while building the collection, this will require iterating the array, so all solutions will be O(N).

However, it may be possible to vectorize using single-instruction multiple-data architecture (such as SSE on Intel, Neon on ARM), dramatically cutting the number of loop iterations.  This will work best if your data is aligned and a multiple of the SIMD stride, otherwise you'll need to handle end effects.  And some compilers may even do this automatically.

Another thing to consider is early exit.  For example, the `count_of` function mentioned in another answer will always iterate the entire array, even if the first two elements are different.  So that's a deoptimization compared to the naive approach with explicit iteration.

Comment: Early exit check is not an option here as I always need to see if the whole array is true.

Comment: @MichaelIV even if the first element is false?

Comment: I start with all the elements as false.Then in runtime they are turned to false randomly.It is never done in any sort of deterministic order.

Comment: @Michael: If you are asking "Is the whole array true?", I can answer that question as soon as I find a single false element.  That's early exit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/) with the appropriate condition.

Alternatively, `count`, `count_if`, `find_if`, `any_of`, `none_of` can also be used for this purpose. `count` variations will not early exit, so will always iterate over the entire array.

If you want not iteration based methods I can think of two rather hacky methods.

1. Keep track of inserts - a count `num_true` which is modified every time you make an insert or a set. Later this can be used to verify your condition.
2. If it is a pure array you could do some [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) stuff to compare against an all-true array and see if it is identical. This might be marginally faster.

Comment: Probably this one still iterates over the whole array?At least it is a nice shortcut :)

Comment: Convenient but effectively still iterating through the array.

Comment: @MichaelIV you cant check the entire array without checking the entire array :)

Comment: All I can save for you is your own effort to code in the iteration.

Comment: Does `memcmp` forbid aliasing?  It could be faster to compare against a shifted view of itself.

Comment: Also, if a `false` changes to `true`, how do you know whether to set `all_true`?  You don't know if that was the *last* `false` in the array if you only kept a boolean flag.

Comment: @BenVoigt you are correct, I guess I was thinking only in terms of inserts.. As to your other question, I don't think i know enough to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a function to do that automaticaly.

But anyway you have to test each member of the array, so it can't be faster than the iteration solution

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @Saksham: No, it answers "Is there a (fast) way without array iteration?".

Comment: That's true, but I'm not allowed to comment

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop to iterate over all the objects and check them.

You might be able to improve performance with loop **[optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization)**.

Besides that, if the data exists inside the container (no pointers), and the architecture allows it, you could use **[SSE](http://sci.tuomastonteri.fi/programming/sse)** vectorization to increase overall performance

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the array status by encapsuling access to it and keep a record of how many entry are set to true.

At initialization of the array to false, set the counter to 0. Each time an entry change from false to true, increment the counter and when an entry goes from true to false, decrement it.

Now, you can with a single test check if the array is all true, all false or a mix.